# Qt5/QML Displaying a custom route on a map

Tags: maps, qml, qt5, openstreetmap

What would be the best way to draw a custom route on a QML Map with a set of given coordinates?
Basically, all I need is that the map highlights the path along the road and does not go straight to each point.
No animations needed either.

Edit:
I need it to be in a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to display a HTML website using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). Both support displaying a GPX track. The track can be obtained by using one of the various [online routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

Comment: I actually need a desktop application. Not a webview. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: Then you will have to either pre-cache [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) or [render](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) them on your own.

Comment: Well, I found that if I add the waypoints at every intersection, then it follows the path I need it to.  The only drawback is that there needs to be a lot more data.